# Clicking on bronze tag badge button shows silver badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, hyperlinks

I just discovered what I think is a bug in the SE engine (confirmed it on SE, programmers and meta):

1. Go to the Badges page (while logged in).
2. Click the Tags button.
3. Click the Bronze Tag Badge button in the lower right corner.
4. Bug: You are shown with the silver tag badges!

You can see that the URL for the Bronze Tag Badge button indeed contains something like `&filter=silver` so I guess that's where the problem lies?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Bronze tag badge goes to a bronze tag badge as expected.

Comment: @Oded the `bronze` button immediately below the `general` / `tags` switch is fine; it's the `bronze tag badge` at the bottom of the right sidebar that's the problem

Comment: @AakashM - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Although also, the *tooltip* for the `bronze` button immediately below the `general` / `tags` switch incorrectly says "silver badges"

Comment: @AakashM - also fixed in the next build, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COPY PASTE BABY, fine for applying links to these, unless you forget to change the filter...

Will be fixed in the next build!

Comment: Been there done that :)